# is there something like group by that also allows me to query individual rows in each group?

Tags: postgresql

I work with PostgreSQL 11.4 and I want to resolve the following issue:

lets say I have the following table:

```
foo | bar
---------
a     null
a     2
a     8
a     3
b     2
c     null
c     8
c     5
c     2
```

I would like to get all the fields in foo where it as at least one null and one none-null value in bar.

so the expected results would be `a` and `c` since these are the only keys that has at least one null and one non-null values

notice that I don't have a unique primary key here, so I can't really do several joins to the table based on foo and to check each join or something.

does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this issue?

any information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use two EXISTS conditions:

```
select distinct foo
from the_table t1
where exists (select * 
              from the_table t2
              where t2.bar is null
                and t2.foo = t1.foo)
  and exists (select * 
              from the_table t3
              where t3.bar is not null
                and t3.foo = t1.foo)
```

Another option is to group by foo and count the rows:

```
select foo
from the_table
group by foo
having count(*) filter (where bar is null) > 0
   and count(*) filter (where bar is not null) > 0;
```

The first one is probably faster though

Answer (score 0):

you can use the with clause, select all foos with nulls and then select all foos with non nulls...

```
with temp_null as 
(
    select distinct on (foo)
    *
    from public.tbl_test2
    where bar is null
),
temp_notnull as
(
    select distinct on (foo)
    *
    from public.tbl_test2
    where bar is not null 
)

select distinct on (foo)
foo
 from public.tbl_test2
where foo in (select foo from temp_null)
and foo in (select foo from temp_notnull)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not having a primary key shouldn't affect your ability to join. The following seems to do what you are asking:

```
create table foobar (foo  VARCHAR (50),bar int);
insert into foobar (foo,bar) 
values('a',null),
('a',2),
('a',8),
('a',3),
('b',2),
('c',null),
('c',8),
('c',5),
('c',2);

select a.foo from foobar a
JOIN foobar b
on b.foo = a.foo
where a.bar is null 
and b.bar is not null
group by a.foo;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be97f3/14